# Service is stopped after a few minuets of inactivity

Tags: android, service, gps, locationmanager, taskmanager

I am writing an android app using the GPS location provider in a Service that is started when the main Activity is created (unless the service is already running). I was under the impression that the service would continue to run with the unlikely exception that the task manager could killed it if there was a memory shortage. For some reason the service is restarted if there is a period of very low activity regardless of how much memory is available. When the user is outside and the GPS is able to resolve a position, the service will get a position every 30 seconds and turn off the gps in between (to save battery). In this case the service continues to run without any problems but when a user moves inside and a gps position can't be found within five seconds, then the service turns off the gps and will only reactivate the GPS every 200 seconds to check if the user has moved back outdoors. In this case the service will sometimes be stopped and won't be restarted until the app is reopened and the activity restarts the service. I created a separate service to make sure the process was uninterrupted. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Thanks so much for your help! -Dom

Comment: Do you have your wakelocks properly set up?

Comment: what are wakelocks? sorry i'm kind of a noob

Comment: so in my case a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK would do?

Comment: Yes, but please study the code sample below to understand how to implement it. It's not as straight forward as it may seem at first. And one more thing. Turning off gps after only 30 seconds may not be the right way to go. It may not be giving the phone enough time to re-acquire gps. You will have to test that and possibly keep the gps radio on continuously.

Comment: The Navilink 3.0 GPS chip (in my Droid X) takes about 3-5 seconds to calculate a position outdoors with a clear view of the sky. I haven't noticed a degradation in accuracy either (vs. constantly enabled). Do you think there might be other consequences to turning it on and off every 30 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look at Mark Murphy's example that deals with Services and Wakelocks:

[WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)

If you can't figure it out from his code example, then you want to get his Advanced Android book where the problem is explained in detail.

[The Busy Coder's Guide to Advanced Android Development](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/)

These are some of the best books on Android development and well worth the minimal cost.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll need to research more about pending intent and application context to understand what this is all about.